# How can I track all the files opened by a software?

Tags: c#, system, message, monitor, total-commander

I want to write a monitor program. It will monitor a special software. When this software open files, it remember the launch history. So I can make my own "Favorite file" or "History" system for some software.

i.e. I use Total Commander frequently. I used tc as a program launcher. Most of my docs or programs opened in TC. But TC does not have a open file history system. So I plan to make one.

When the files opened in TC. TC is the parent process.  I think there is a way to write C# code to get all the files opened by TC (It is about message sending and monitor code).  TC is written in delphin, It use stand listbox control. C# could solve the problem nice.

But I am new to C#, I have a little Autohotkey and python programming skill. I am learning C# now. Can someone give me some tips to write the code?  Core idea is OK, I will handle with the GUI things.

Comment: do the sysinternals tools include source code?

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to write your own.  Process monitor from sysinternals/Microsoft can monitor files.  And with the filters you can filter by process.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I know some tools can monitor the message. But My goal is to make a small tools like  "favorite files list". I write the code to collect history data, and export the data to a listbox. It is like "recent open file" in TC.

Answer (score 0):

im also doing a child monitoring software for university project.
i found a few solutions for doing this.

1. Windows HOOK and intercept all the fileread write..etc.(hard & complex)
2. why not just check MyRecentDocuments folder... :P ( user may change settings which has both pros and cons)

donno if we can use "Process" class and do something.. :P

EDIT----------------

i almost forgot...
when i was implementing the Process Monitoring Component, i found that when a user double clicks a file "dllhost.exe" gets to run. :) i guess u hv a clue of what to do now.. im also still working on it..